# How to display grep results with the search pattern omitted?

Tags: linux, grep

For instance:

file.txt contains

```
this is a string
this is another string
```

grep "this is" file.txt should output:

```
 a string
 another string
```

Comment: If a line does not match the search pattern at all, should it be shown entirely, or not at all? Do you need to use grep specifically?

Comment: Easy way: don't use grep

Comment: @mattdm: see my edited question

Comment: That doesn't answer _either_ of my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got GNU grep, then using this `(?<=)` "look-behind" *should* work:

```
$ echo -e "this is a string\nthis is another string"
this is a string
this is another string

$ echo -e "this is a string\nthis is another string" | grep -Po '(?<=this is).+'
 a string
 another string
```

Some regex lookahead & lookbehind info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

---

Or using `sed`

```
sed 's/this is//'
```

or

```
sed -n 's/this is//p'
```

Comment: Yes, it does the trick.

Comment: This only works with the pattern at the beginning of the line; it's not clear that's intended. (But `sed` works.)

Comment: @mattdm the grep command seems to work for me with "this is" in the middle of a line, returning only the characters beyond "this is"... ex: `echo -e "now this is a string" | grep -Po '(?<=this is).+'` returns "`a string` ". Maybe your grep is a little different. Also note the option `-P, --perl-regexp` *Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  Perl regular expression (PCRE, see below). This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.*